# Riemannian Distance is always greater?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, metric-geometry

---

**Setup:**

Suppose $M$ is a $C^k$-manifold embedded into some Hilbert space $H$ and $g$ is the induced [Riemannian metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#Riemannian_metrics) thereon (induced by restricting the inner-product $\langle,\rangle_H $ in $H$ to the tangent spaces of $M$).

Let $g_H(x,y):= \sqrt{\langle (x-y),(x-y)\rangle_H}$.

---

**Question:**

Then is it necessarily the case that:
\begin{align}
(\forall x,y \in M)\, g_H(x,y)\leq g(x,y)?
\end{align}

---

**Intuitive Reasoning**

This seems to intuitively be true as the "shortest distance" between two points is a straight line and $M$ may be curved..

Comment: Is $g(x, y) = \inf\{ \int_0^1 |\dot \gamma|: \gamma :[0,1]\to M, \gamma(0) = x, \gamma(1) = y\}$?

Comment: Yes, this is the same as the pullback metric: $i^{\star}(d_H)$ where $i:M \hookrightarrow H$ the inclusion.

Comment: I think the common notation is that $i^* f(x, y)  =f(i(x), i(y))$, so indeed $i^* d = d_H$, where $d$ is the metric on $H$.

Comment: @CSA: Your intuitive reasoning is correct if by "$g$" you mean the function in John Ma's first comment (a topological metric), _not_ the Riemannian metric on $M$ induced by the embedding (which makes no sense applied to a pair of points of $M$). That is, it's crucial to distinguish the _induced Riemannian metric_ (an apple) and the _induced topological metric_ obtained by "joining points by shortest curves" (an orange).

Comment: How would I prove this for John Ma's definition?
Also why is this false for the pull-back metric $g_p(x,y):=g_{H}(d_pi(x),d_pi(y))$?

(Also I modified my notation not to confuse the differential with the metric on H).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make your intuition precise, we should prove that the arclength $\int |\dot \gamma|$ of *any* ($C^1$) curve $\gamma$ joining $x$ and $y$ is at least $|x-y| = g_H(x,y)$.

Let's start by defining a "horizontal axis" to measure along: Let $v = \frac{x-y}{|x-y|}$ and define $h(p) = \langle p-y, v \rangle$, so that $h$ is an affine function with $h(y) = 0$, $h(x) = |x-y|$ and unit-length gradient (don't worry about making this last claim precise).

We want to show that the arclength is bounded below by $h(\gamma(1))$ and we know that $h(\gamma(0))=0$, so it suffices to show that

$$\frac{d}{dt} h(\gamma(t)) \le |\dot \gamma| = \frac{d}{dt} \int_0^t |\dot \gamma|.$$

This is now simple - just apply Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$ \frac d{dt} h(\gamma(t)) = \frac d{dt} \langle \gamma(t) - y, v\rangle = \langle \dot \gamma(t),v \rangle \le |\dot \gamma||v| = |\dot \gamma|.$$